# How long do I sous-vide a 5.5lb veal breast?

Tags: sous-vide

How long and at what temperature should I sous-vide a 5.5lb veal breast?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a spreadsheet with recommended heating and pasteurization times for different meats and temperatures for sous vide?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/75343/is-there-a-spreadsheet-with-recommended-heating-and-pasteurization-times-for-dif)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the thickness of the meat and how well done you like it.  There's an excellent reference here: http://douglasbaldwin.com/sous-vide.html#Beef

Answer (score 0):

I cooked three boneless rib roasts sous-vide , about six or seven pounds each, in an insulated cooler at 137 for six hours, they were a nice medium rare. I know it's not the same but maybe that will give you some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Brown all sides, sous vide 67 degrees Celsius for 48 hours...your friends will celebrate your result...

Comment: Some googling suggests the temperature is high, and the cooking time far too long. For instance, treating veal as a thin and tender beef cut, the guide linked to below (http://www.douglasbaldwin.com/sous-vide.html#Beef) recommends at most one hour at 60 Celsius.